# How do I remove a package?

Tags: package

I just began using Elementary OS and I am having a problem with videos. I found what might be a solution here on Stack Exchange, that suggests removing a package, but being one-day old here I have only a small idea of what might be involved in removing a package, just that it probably involves the command line interface. However I would like some clear instructions as to how to go about removing a package. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the shell you can remove a package with the command:

```
sudo apt remove packagename
```

after that I would suggest to run the following command to remove unused dependencies:

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

You can also remove package from the app center, just select the package and click <kbd>uninstall</kbd>.